# Debug in a function: cannot list zipped objects?

Tags: python, debugging, zip, pdb

I'm trying to debug a function `one_away` like this:

```
import pdb


def is_one_away(first: str, other: str) -> bool:

    skip_diff = {
        -1: lambda i: (i, i + 1),
        1: lambda i: (i + 1, i),
        0: lambda i: (i + 1, i + 1)
    }
    try:
        skip = skip_diff[len(first) - len(other)]
    except KeyError:
        return False
    pdb.set_trace()
    for i, (l1, l2) in enumerate(zip(first, other)):
        if l1 != l2:
            i -= 1
            break
```

And to call it I write:

```
import one_away
one_away.is_one_away('pale', 'kale')
```

When running to `pdb.set_trace()`, I'd like to see the result of `zip(first ,other)`. So I write:

```
(Pdb) >? list(zip(first, other))
*** Error in argument: '(zip(first, other))'
```

But if in Python console, it works:

```
>>>list(zip('pale', 'kale'))
[('p', 'k'), ('a', 'a'), ('l', 'l'), ('e', 'e')]
```

Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`list` is a built-in command in the debugging shell:

```
(Pdb) help list
l(ist) [first [,last] | .]

        List source code for the current file.  Without arguments,
        list 11 lines around the current line or continue the previous
        listing.  With . as argument, list 11 lines around the current
        line.  With one argument, list 11 lines starting at that line.
        With two arguments, list the given range; if the second
        argument is less than the first, it is a count.

        The current line in the current frame is indicated by "->".
        If an exception is being debugged, the line where the
        exception was originally raised or propagated is indicated by
        ">>", if it differs from the current line.
```

So when you type

```
(Pdb) list(zip(first, other))
```

it tries to interpret that as a command passed to pdb. Instead you want to execute (or `p`rint) an expression in python:

```
(Pdb) list(zip(first, other))
*** Error in argument: '(zip(first, other))'
(Pdb) !list(zip(first, other))
[('p', 'k'), ('a', 'a'), ('l', 'l'), ('e', 'e')]
(Pdb) p list(zip(first, other))
[('p', 'k'), ('a', 'a'), ('l', 'l'), ('e', 'e')]
```